# Parametric bootstrap testing for random effect in GLMM

Tags: self-study, mixed-model, glmm, lme4-nlme

I am trying to learn GLMM using `R`. From what I have understood parametric bootstrap is a robust method to know the significance of fixed as well as random effects in the model (http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq). The function `PBmodcomp` of the `R` package `pbkrtest` can be used for testing the significance of the fixed effects.

Similarly how to perform parametric bootstrap testing for random effects in the model. particularly when there are multiple random effects `(1|f1) + (1|f2)` or random effects terms such as `(1 + f1 + f2|id)` (id is repeated within f1 and f2)?

Comment: Did you look at `bootMer` as suggested in the [FAQ](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq) you linked to ? ? This can do parametric and semi-parametric bootstrap resampling for GLMMs